# Аналог "C:\Users\Public" (%Public%) в десктопном Linux

Tags: linux, администрирование, desktop

Мне понадобилось вытаскивать файлы .desktop на рабочий стол, чтобы пользователи не искали их в Start Menu.

Отсюда вопрос, eсть ли какая-то папка (желательно в стандарте freedesktop), как в Windows из заголовка вопроса?

Всем, кто захочет советовать `/etc/skel`, хочу напомнить, что это - только для НОВЫХ профилей.

Я умею в `for i in $var ; do ; done`, но не хочу.

Comment: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я видимо тупой, потому что прочёл 3 раза, 2 из которых с потомщью гугл переводчика и главный админ тоже прочёл. Но мы так и не нашли ответа в ссылке. Можешь ткнуть конкретнее?

Comment: $XDG_DATA_DIRS defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for data files in addition to the $XDG_DATA_HOME base directory. The directories in $XDG_DATA_DIRS should be seperated with a colon ':'.

Comment: If $XDG_DATA_DIRS is either not set or empty, a value equal to **/usr/local/share/**:/usr/share/ should be used.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, перепрочёл, поискал про переменную в интернете, но так и не понял, почему она должна выкидывать нужные мне ярлыки на рабочий стол пользователя.

Comment: А какие могут быть причины **не** "выкидывать" эти ярлыки?

Comment: Они же берутся не непонятно откуда, а из поддиректории $XDG_DATA_HOME. Дальше читаем: *"$XDG_DATA_DIRS defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for data files in addition to the $XDG_DATA_HOME base directory."*

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну а дальше-то что? В какую папку положить и/или какие значения этим переменным задать, чтобы на рабочих столах всех пользователей появились новые ярлыки? Я вот тоже ничего не понял, по вашей ссылке рабочий стол вообще даже не упоминается

Comment: @andreymal да я вот тоже не нашёл где рабочий стол в линуксе, но предполагаю что задающий вопрос уже его нашёл

Comment: @andreymal надо найти где рабочий стол пользователя, и заменить `~/.share` на `/usr/local/share`

Comment: @PavelMayorov допустим, мой рабочий стол находится по адресу `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=/home/andreymal/data/Рабочий стол` — что на что тут заменять?

Comment: Я нашёл `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`, но это только названия папок.

Comment: @PavelMayorov `А какие могут быть причины не "выкидывать" эти ярлыки?`. Для пользователя - все программы, которые НЕ на рабочем столе - НЕ установлены. А значит - звонки, письма, служебки о том, что "уроды-программисты сломали компуцкер и я не могу работать".

Comment: @donRumata вы сейчас что-то странное написали

Comment: @andreymal а, вот куда его запрятали. Ну, значит, та ссылка и правда бесполезная.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну ты же спрашивал зачем вытаскивать ярлыки на рабочий стол? Я правильно понял?

Comment: @donRumata это был вообще не вопрос, а ответ на предыдущий комментарий в форме риторического вопроса

Comment: @PavelMayorov, теперь я запутался :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. стандарта нет или мы его не нашли, то сделал костыль (имхо, достаточно элегантный, но костыль).

Ставим пакет `symlinks` для чистки битых симлинков.

Создаём нужные <s>папки</s> каталоги:

`tree /home/public/`

```
/home/public/
├── Desktop
├── Documents
├── Downloads
├── Music
├── Pictures
├── Public
├── Templates
└── Videos
```

Разрешаем всем `read only`:

`chmod -R 755 /home/public/`

Создаём `.desktop` файл для автозагрузки:

`/etc/xdg/autostart/create-symlinks-to-desktop-from-public-directory.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Create symlinks 4 any files in %Public% 4 current user
Comment=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1438407/191416
Exec=/usr/local/bin/create-symlinks-to-desktop-from-public-directory.sh
RunHook=0
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

и скрипт:

`/usr/local/bin/create-symlinks-to-desktop-from-public-directory.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Получаем переменные XDG_*
source "$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs"
# Создаём симлинки из всего, что находится в "%Public%/Desktop" для рабочего стола конкретного пользователя.
ln -s /home/public/Desktop/* "$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR"/
# Переходим в папку рабочего стола.
cd "$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR"
# Чистим битые симлинки, если из "%Public%/Desktop" было что-то удалено - у пользователя оно тоже почистится.
symlinks -d ./
```

В итоге - всё, что будет кидаться (rsync\curl\ssh\ansible\mount.nfs\руками) в `/home/public/Desktop` - при логоне пользователя будет копироваться в виде ярлыка на его рабочий стол. При удалении из `/home/public/Desktop` - симлинк у пользователя будет становиться битым и удаляться.

Всё тоже самое, но через `ansible`:

```yaml
---
# WORK
  - name: Config directory %Public%
    hosts: all
    strategy: free
    serial:
      - "100%"
    vars:
      paths_to_public_directory:
        root: /home/public
        user_dirs:
          desktop: Desktop
          downloads: Downloads
          templates: Templates
          public: Public
          documents: Documents
          music: Music
          pictures: Pictures
          videos: Videos
    tasks:

# https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1438407/191416
# /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults
    - name: Config %Public% 4 Linux
      when: ansible_system == 'Linux'
      become: yes
      block:
        - user:
            name: public
            system: yes
            state: present
            create_home: yes
            home: "{{ paths_to_public_directory.root }}"
            comment: "ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1438407/191416"
            expires: -1
        - acl:
            path: "{{ paths_to_public_directory.root }}"
            etype: other
            permissions: rx
            default: yes
            recursive: yes
            state: present
        - file:
            path: "{{ paths_to_public_directory.root }}"
            state: directory
            mode: '755'
        - file:
            path: "{{ paths_to_public_directory.root }}/{{ item.value }}"
            state: directory
            mode: '755'
          with_dict: "{{ paths_to_public_directory.user_dirs }}"

    - name: Create symlinks 4 any files in %Public% 4 current user
      when:
        - ansible_system == 'Linux'
      become: yes
      block:
        - copy:
            dest: /etc/xdg/autostart/create-symlinks-to-desktop-from-public-directory.desktop
            content: |
              [Desktop Entry]
              Encoding=UTF-8
              Type=Application
              Name=Create symlinks 4 any files in %Public% 4 current user
              Comment=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1438407/191416
              Exec=/usr/local/bin/create-symlinks-to-desktop-from-public-directory.sh
              RunHook=0
              StartupNotify=false
              Terminal=false
              Hidden=false
            mode: '644'
        - copy:
            dest: /usr/local/bin/create-symlinks-to-desktop-from-public-directory.sh
            content: |
              #!/usr/bin/env bash

              # Получаем переменные XDG_*
              source "$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs"
              # Создаём симлинки из всего, что находится в "%Public%/Desktop" для рабочего стола конкретного пользователя.
              ln -s {{ paths_to_public_directory.root }}/Desktop/* "$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR"/
              # Переходим в папку рабочего стола.
              cd "$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR"
              # Чистим битые симлинки, если из "%Public%/Desktop" было что-то удалено - у пользователя оно тоже почистится.
              symlinks -d ./

            mode: '755'
```